# Python letter guess game

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, counter

I want to create the hangman python game, so I created a simpler piece of the game. The idea of the game is to guess the letters in a randomly generated word. Here is what I have so far. I listed the problem and questions I have at the bottom.

```
import random


words = ['holiday', 'american', 'restaurant', 'computer', 'highschool', 'programming']
random_word = random.choice(words)
count = 0


while True:                                     #repeatedly asks you to guess the letter in a random word
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter:  "))
    guess = guess.lower()


    if guess in random_word:             #checks if the letter you input is in the random generated word
        print("Yay, its in the word")
      
    
    else:                          
        count += 1
        print("Not in the word, attempts: %d" % count)
        
        if count > 5:                   
            print("You have reached max attempts")
            print("Sorry, but hangman died! You lose")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

The problem I have: **When the user guesses a letter, they can guess it again infinite times. How can I make it so that the user can't repeatedly guess the same letter?**

Is there a way to make sure the user doesn't guess the same letter? This could be a problem in an actual hangman game when there are several letters that are the same. Any help/feedback appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Then you either need a list of guessed letter, or create a copy of the current word and remove each guessed letter from that copy.

Comment: How would you do it when you play live in person, on paper? For that matter: when someone in a real hangman game correctly guesses a letter, what do you do (how do you mark up the paper) that your program isn't doing yet? Think about the record-keeping that needs to be done. You cannot ever expect to program anything that you cannot first clearly describe in the plain words of your native language.

Comment: As Martheen mentioned you can have a list like bellow and append each guess to it to track the already typed words and check if the guessed word is already in that list.
`guessed_words = [] 
guessed_words.append(guess)`
For each guess you can check if the guess is in guessed_words list or not like bellow (in while loop):
`if guess in guessed_words:
    continue
else:
    print('You already guessed this word.')
    `

Comment: agree with @KarlKnechtel.  Think about the problem and be very precise about it.  Then think about the solution, and then about the code.  In that sense, this question is related to python as much as this sentence is related to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
import random


words = ['holiday', 'american', 'restaurant', 'computer', 'highschool', 'programming']
random_word = random.choice(words)
count = 0
guess_list = []

while True:                                     #repeatedly asks you to guess the letter in a random word
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter:  "))
    guess = guess.lower()

    if guess not in guess_list:
        if guess in random_word:             #checks if the letter you input is in the random generated word
            print("Yay, its in the word")

        else:                          
            count += 1
            print("Not in the word, attempts: %d" % count)

            if count > 5:                   
                print("You have reached max attempts")
                print("Sorry, but hangman died! You lose")
                break
                
    else:
        print("You have already guessed {}. Try again".format(guess))
        print(set(guess_list))
        
    guess_list.append(guess)
```

Sample output (word is computer):

```
Guess a letter:  c
Yay, its in the word
Guess a letter:  e
Yay, its in the word
Guess a letter:  e
You have already guessed e. Try again
{'e', 'c'}
Guess a letter:  e
You have already guessed e. Try again
{'e', 'c'}
Guess a letter:  w
Not in the word, attempts: 1
Guess a letter:  m
Yay, its in the word
Guess a letter:  m
You have already guessed m. Try again
{'w', 'm', 'e', 'c'}
Guess a letter:
```

Notes:

1. A guess_list is created that keeps record of all the guesses.
2. After each guess the letter is appended to the list.
3. When the user repeats the guess they are warned. We use a set so only the unique elements in the guess list are displayed.

The code can be refined further, but must do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for this new approach. I am a new programmer, so I definitely need to read into the documentation more. I will keep at it, thankyou.

Comment: Did you try running the above code? Does it do what you expected?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help. I am trying different versions, but I think I am on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the word, you may need to allow multiple guesses if the letter appears more than once.  (this may not be your requirement.  Not familiar with the game.)

### Approach

What you need is a store that keeps track of the number of occurrences of each letter in the word.

Something like:

```
letterCounts = Counter("hello") # word: 'hello' => {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

I'm using the [counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) collection here.

Then you can decrement the count of the guessed letter

```
if guesses_letter in list(letterCounts.elements()):
    if (letterCounts[guessed_letter] > 0):
        letterCounts[guessed_letter] -= 1
    else:
        # the letter can't be repeated now.  do the needful here.
```